# Implementing interface. How to extend property type?

Tags: flowtype

In my React project I have a couple components that share a similar shape (properties and methods). In order to keep things maintainable, I created a common interface for them:

```
interface IControl {
  props: {
    title: string;
  }
}
```

But whenever I implement this interface on a component whose props are a superset of `IControl`'s, I get an error:

```
8:   props: {            ^ property `onClick`. Property not found in 
2:   props: {            ^ object type
```

## [Try it out](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED24qYDbIDeAUMsgA67kDOAXEaWcmMGHhPdWFKAOYDcjAL7ERxBHjjVqyAGKZMWALblsEcMmAr2S9WBkZs3fAzKVMNeiSbNW7Ttz6Cb2dHmAIA1vQAUASmQAXgA+ZAA3TGAAE2dkETEgA)

Full example source code:

```
interface IControl {
  props: {
    title: string;
  }
}

class FooComponent implements IControl {
  props: {
    title: string;
    onClick: () => void;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because objects in JS are mutable, and I could take an instance of `IControl` and assign `props` to it, without the props required by the implementing class. Here is the solution (it's a one character change):

```
interface IControl {
  +props: {
    title: string;
  }
}

class FooComponent implements IControl {
  props: {
    title: string;
    onClick: () => void;
  }
}

const x: IControl = new FooComponent();

x.props = {title: 'asdf'};

(x.props.title: string)
```

([try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED24qYDbIDeAUMsgNQAOulAzgFxGlnJjBh4SO1hSgDmAbmYBfYmOII8cWrWQAxTJiwBbStgjhkwNZxWawcjNl74mZapjqMSLVu07deA4Xezo8wBAGtGACgBKZABeAD5kADdMYAATV2QxCQRsHmQAD0ZjHDNg5BAIAHcFJVV1fPBA4WI0gDpLOhCiNg4uZAByGRiYNpEqv1r62hrmx2QePhB+AKA))

This makes use of [property variance](https://flowtype.org/blog/2016/10/04/Property-Variance.html). You can see that it disallows the incorrect assignment, but it does allow an access of `x.props.title`.